# Integral involving distance to the boundary

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega$ be a  bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\alpha<1$. My question is when the integral
$$
\int_{\Omega}\frac{dx}{\text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)^{\alpha}}
$$
is finite?

Comment: Do you mean $\partial\overline{\Omega}$?

Comment: Is that a difference?

Comment: Are you asking for conditions on $\Omega $ and $\partial \Omega $?   The integral will always be finite if the boundary is smooth and both $\Omega $ and $\partial \Omega $ have finite measure.

Comment: @Yly Not if $\Omega$ is not bounded. I think taking $\overline{\Omega}$ compact will simplify many things.

Comment: Yes, $\Omega$ is bounded, I forgot about that.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for conditions on $\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$. Is there any characterisation?

Comment: @JeanMarie Unless I'm mistaken, having $|\partial \Omega|$ finite will control the blowup of the integral near the boundary, and having $|\Omega|$ finite will control divergence on the interior.  I think boundedness of $\Omega$ is irrelevant as long as the relevant volume and area are finite.  I don't have time to work through all the details right now (but maybe tomorrow), but in the meantime, if you see a flaw in this, could you please elaborate?